# Confusion related to ordinary kriging

Tags: normal-distribution, covariance, gaussian-process, variogram, kriging

I was reading this wiki [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kriging) related to ordinary kriging where they calculated the weights like this

I know that covariance from the covariogram and semivariance from the semivariogram are different things. However, when they generated the weights, they have used the ones from the variogram instead of the covariogram. How are they equal? I am confused about this. I didn't get how they equated $Var_{x_i}$ to the semivariogram $\gamma(x_1,x_1) .....$.

Also when I tried to estimate the weights in the case of my data using the semivariogram params, it was not invertible. I guess, I am doing something wrong. I am not sure why are we using the semivariogram params instead of the covariance in the first place

Suggestions guys

[image]